# cSplit seems not have any affect

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
> library(splitstackshape)
> head(goa)
       V2         V5
1: A0A000 GO:0003824
2: A0A000 GO:0003870
3: A0A000 GO:0009058
4: A0A000 GO:0030170
5: A0A000 GO:0033014
6: A0A001 GO:0000166
```

and I would like to get this table:

```
> library(splitstackshape)
> head(goa)
       V2         V5
1: A0A000 GO:0003824,GO:0003870,GO:0009058,GO:0030170,GO:0033014
2: A0A001 GO:0000166
```

I tried to use `cSplit` in the below way but it did not change anything.

```
> goa <- cSplit(goa, "V5", ",", "long")
> head(goa)
       V2         V5
1: A0A000 GO:0003824
2: A0A000 GO:0003870
3: A0A000 GO:0009058
4: A0A000 GO:0030170
5: A0A000 GO:0033014
6: A0A001 GO:0000166
```

What did I miss?

Comment: `cSplit` is not suitable here. You may try `aggregate(V2~V5, df, toString)`.

Comment: Thank you. I had to change it to `goa <- aggregate(V5~V2, goa, toString)`